# How does US/UK scoring work for the invasion of Japan?

Tags: churchill

In the game [Churchill](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/132018/churchill), how does US/UK scoring work for the invasion of Japan?  We've been poring over the rules, coming to several different conclusions.

If all US/UK fronts invade Japan at once, how many points do the US/UK each get for the invasion:

- 24,
- 8,
- or some other amount?

---

Japan can be invaded by four different fronts: the USSR from the north, and the US/UK from the west, south, and east.  For this question, we can ignore the northern front.

[image: invasion of Japan]

At the end of the game, anywhere from zero to three of these fronts could be occupying Japan.  According to [the rules](http://www.gmtgames.com/churchill/CHURCHILLRules-Final.pdf) (p 18):

> A Front scores points for the furthest space it has advanced toward, or into, an Axis country.  A player does not score points for spaces that the Front passed through, just the last space it advanced into, to include an Axis country.

and, regarding how many points players get if Germany/Japan surrender:

> 8 [points] per Axis country where they have a Front (all US and UK Fronts give 8 points to both the US and the UK)

So let's say all three fronts have made it into Japan (since we're ignoring the northern front).  How many points is that worth for the US/UK?

- 24 points, because (regarding surrendered Axis countries) "**all** US and UK Fronts **give 8 points** to both the US and the UK"
- 8 points, because players receive "8 VP per Axis country **where they have a Front**"

24 points seems unlikely, because that's an *enormous* number of points to get, in a game where the US/UK get only 8 points for conquering Germany.

8 points seems unlikely, because that would mean the US *loses* two points for invading past Kyushu and Okinawa.

How does the scoring actually work?

Answer (score 1):

According to Q&A:

> **How many points does a player receive for Japan surrender if they have more than one front in that Axis country?**
>
> Per rule 9.4.G each player receives 8 VP per Axis Country (NOT front) where they have a Front. So, if the US Central and SW Pacific Fronts enter Japan during the same conference the US and the UK receive 8 VPs each , NOT 16. If in addition to this example the CBI Front also entered Japan, the same outcome would pertain. Additionally, since you only receive VPs for the last space that a front occupies this can lower a player’s potential score in some instances and is a known and intended result.

Link: https://www.gmtgames.com/churchill/ChurchillErrataClarifications2Sep2015.pdf